# My condition does not return the header i selected. Why that?

Tags: php

```
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO images (file_name, uploaded_on, name, code) VALUES (:image, NOW(), :name, :code)');
  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':code', $_POST['code']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':image', $fileNameNew);
  $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      header("Location: succes.html");
    } else {
      header("Location: bazadedate.html");
    }
```

Hello everybody i have this condition here which IF STMT inserts data to my Database redirects me to succes.html and if not it does redirect me to bazadedate.html

The problem is that $stmt inserts data to my database perfectly, but instead to redirect me at succes.html it redirects me to bazadedate.html... and is wrong... How can i figure this out ?

Comment: Because you call `$stmt->execute();` twice.  Get rid of the first one.

Comment: you are executing twice. Vote to close as typo

Comment: @abracadaver so if i get rid of the first one, the command "stmt->execute" will also run ?

Comment: Yes it’s in the if